# C# - T type, array, list indexing

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I want to write a method where i can send any type of `[]`, `List<>`...etc. But in the code when I use T and I want to index the input array, list or anything the error says "Cannot apply indexing with `[]` to an expression of type 'T'". Theres any solution for this or I have to write a separate code for array, list..etc?

```cs
public void NormSort<T>(ref T input, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
        {
            if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(input[i], input[j]) > 0)
            {
                Swap<T>(input[i], input[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void Swap<T>(T item1, T item2)
 {
     var temp = item1;
     item1 = item2;
     item2 = temp;
 }
```

So wheres the input[i], input[j], there i got that error.

Comment: For reference, it *looks* like you're used to using C/C++ pointers (this code reeks of being lifted from pointer-based code); what you're trying to do here maps very well to the upcoming `Span<T>` mechanism; you should be able to *create* a `Span<T>` over most arrays and contiguous lists, and it allows in-place `ref` access to the data. That isn't an option *today*, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is probably to make the parameter `IList<T>` for some `T`, since `IList<T>` has the indexer support *and* both arrays and lists implement `IList<T>`. Note that you *probably* don't need to pass the `n` here, since `IList<T>` also has a `.Count` property. So:

```
public void NormSort<T>(IList<T> input) {
    int n = input.Count;
    // ...
}
```

Note that your `Swap` method won't work, however; that isn't pass-by-`ref`, and even if it was: you can't pass indexer values by ref - you need to get and set separately; perhaps:

```
public static void NormSort<T>(IList<T> input)
{
    int n = input.Count;
    var comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            T x = input[i], y = input[j];
            if (comparer.Compare(x, y) > 0)
            {
                input[i] = y;
                input[j] = x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that a more typical implementation here would be an extension method:

```
public static void Sort<T>(this IList<T> input) {...}
```

Then you can just use:

```
myListOrArray.Sort();
```

and as a nice side-effect, *if* the compiler knows it is a `List<T>`, it will prefer the inbuilt `List<T>.Sort()` which will be more efficient - but it will *compile* for any `IList<T>` type.

Comment: I should of course note that it is *not* necessarily a good idea to be writing your own sorting algorithms. `List<T>.Sort`, `Array.Sort`, etc, are much better options.

Comment: Ohh...So with that i can pass through the whole 
int[] like this -> `List<int[]> asd = new List<int[]>();`
But how to pass through a list?

Comment: @SzabolcsMészáros `var list = new List<int> { 3, 4, 1, 5, 2 }; NormSort(list); System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list));` - note I don't think the algo works right now, but that's an implementation detail

Comment: Note, it was just an example for my problem and its my school task.

Comment: @SzabolcsMészáros you wouldn't normally use a list of arrays - that is "jagged". You almost certainly mean `List<int>` in this case; arrays aren't comparable, for example (you can't ask whether one array is `>` another array).

Comment: Yea, i see, I dont have to give it to a Type like for int[].
Like -> `NormSort<int[]>(asd);`

Comment: @SzabolcsMészáros that is "generic type inference" - you *can* specify the `T` explicitly, but in most cases the compiler can figure it out by itself so it is optional and rarely done. In some cases ("anonymous types"), you **cannot** explicitly specify the `T` (because: it doesn't have a name) - but mostly it is just more convenient to omit it. If you wanted to be explicit: `NormSort<int>`

Comment: yea, it was just my misunderstood of how to pass through that array. Now everything is clear.

Comment: @SzabolcsMészáros btw, I fixed the algo in an edit; both the lower and upper bounds were wrong

Answer (score -2):

Use IEnumerable and you can have all type of collections:

```
public void NormSort<T>(ref IEnumerable<T> input, int n)
{ ...
}
```

Comment: that won't allow indexer usage

Comment: True, but you then have ElementAt(N) or ToArray() and then use the indexer.

Comment: If you use `ToArray` you will be modifying a different enumerable so the sorting won't work.

Comment: @Stefano that is *horribly* inefficient, *and* breaks the intent that you shouldn't rely on enumerables being repeatable, *plus* enumerables don't have a mechanism to change the values, *plus* if you manage to **it breaks the enumerable**; ToArray creates a *copy* of the data, so doesn't help